# How to debug Expression.Lambda? (Difference in Expressions tree evaluation between .net core 2.1 and .net core 3.1)

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.1, ef-core-3.1

I've created a small program that shows some differences between .net core 2.1 and 3.1:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var entityObject = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "objParam");
        var cev = new ExpressionPrinter();
        var entObjPrint = cev.PrintDebug(entityObject);
        Console.WriteLine(entObjPrint);
    }
}
```

the print out in 2.1: Unhandled parameter: objParam

the print out in 3.1: (Unhandled parameter: objParam){0}

notice the brackets and the extra {0} at the end. 
Can someone explain to me why is this difference?

NOTE: This is a shortened version of my issue, but also when I try to compile an Expression.Lambda in .net core 3.1 I get an error (not exception) which is not present in the .net core 2.1 version of my code:

> `{Method = <Internal Error evaluating expression>}`

**UPDATE**: It seems that the `PrintDebug` implementation have changed. If you call `PrintDebug(enitytObject,null,false)` there will no longer be {0}.

With that in mind, maybe the issue is not that, but still I do not know how to debug a compile error of an lambda expression (not to be mistaken with linq lambda).

**More on the issue** This is part of the code where I am getting the error:

```
//return all fields/properties that have an attribute indicating they need to be localized
var locFields = EntityLocalizationReflection.GetLocalizationFields(entityType);
            if (locFields?.Count > 0)
            {
                var updater = new EntityLocalizerUpdater();
                // create a parameter representing an object (object)
                var entityObject = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "objParam");
                // convert the parameter to an IEntityType ((object)Category)
                var entityInstance = Expression.Convert(entityObject, entityType.Metadata.ClrType);
                // iterate over all fields/properties that needs to be localized
                foreach (var loc in locFields)
                {
                    // Depending if the localized element is a field or a property, create the expression
                    var target = loc.Item2.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property
                        ? Expression.Property(entityInstance, (PropertyInfo)loc.Item2)
                        : Expression.Field(entityInstance, (FieldInfo)loc.Item2);

                    var getter = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, EntityLocalizer>>(target, entityObject);false);
//getter.Compile() failes only in .NET code 3.1
                    updater.Add(getter.Compile(), loc.Item1.EntityName);
                }

                //...some other code..//
            }
```

*UPDATE 2*: Thanks to @MarcGravell there is a minimum runnable code here: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/57d5691741e1379f32c2d22540acf8da and the error can be viewed if a "Quick Watch" is performed over `getter.Compile()` or assign some variable to it (`var compiled = getter.Compile();`) and then inspect it during Debug.

Comment: Does it matter what it prints to the console? Isn't that just for debugging purposes?

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but since I am seeing different behavior, I suspect it indicates that some underling code have change and therefor it matters.

Comment: underlying code is allowed to change; that doesn't necessarily indicate a problem; so yes, I entirely acknowledge that it is possible that `PrintDebug` works slightly differently - the history is available [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/commits/master/src/EFCore/Query/ExpressionPrinter.cs) - I'd be looking at c07d362, but that's just a guess (and probably post-dates 3.1); it isn't clear that this would be related to an `<Internal Error evaluating expression>` though

Comment: So it seems @MarcGravell you were right and the `PrintDebug` have change. Do you have any input on how to debug Expression trees?

Comment: @theCuriousOne I have lots of experience with expression trees, but there isn't really much here for me to comment on

Comment: @MarcGravell updaed the question. Tell me if you need more info, but I believe that with the code commends you can figure something out. p.s. I have written the comments while trying to understand the code and not the original author, so maybe I am wrong on somethings.

Comment: @theCuriousOne some info on the type (and the properties) being considered here would help - also, there's a trailing `false`  on the `getter` line that makes it hard to be sure what is going on, because that doesn't compile; are the properties *typed* as `EntityLocalizer`? or are they typed as `string`? or...? and is the type being considered a `class`? a `struct`? a `ref struct`? or...? are they instance or static members?

Comment: (minimal runnable bit here works fine: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/57d5691741e1379f32c2d22540acf8da - so the trick is to find what is different between your scenario and my scenario)

Comment: @MarcGravell WOW. Thanks for the dedication. The code is pretty much spot on and I am seeing the same error in your example as well. Just "Quick Watch" `getter.Compile()`  or assign some variable to it (`var compiled = getter.Compile();` and hopefully you'll see also the error {Method = <Internal Error evaluating expression>}. p.s I am using Visual Studio 16.5.4

Comment: @theCuriousOne so you're actually talking about the IDE debugger here, not the runtime? I can repro the *debugger* not being able to do much with this - it looks like that broke in netcoreapp3.0 (it works in netcoreapp2.2 etc), but this *only* seems to impact the debugger for me - it still *works correctly* in the runtime. If this only impacts the IDE, you should use the Help => Send Feedback => Report a Problem option in the IDE to log it as an IDE bug.

Comment: @MarcGravell already did that https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/33479 (my username is the same ;) ) I am trying to resolve an failing test and that is the only point that I saw an issue, therefore I am not sure if it is the debugger itself or some code from the .net core. Spend 3 days already fighting this. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a debugger issue when showing Expressions in .net core 3.1.
An issue has been open.